# SQL Execute function failed due to special character Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript

Currently, i have written new ASP file to load few records into database through **`cn.Execute`** Method.

But, it throws an below error,

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 616: PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 359: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 717: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;

After that I found that there is special character in one of the field value (like **chr(237)** and **chr (233)**). But, I am able to run the same query through sqlplus, am able to run the query.

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: you already found the problem. we cannot go to your workplace to delete the end-of-file character for you. Clean your code.  And  ' I am able to run the same query through sqlplus' is no excuse, that is not the same interpreter/driver as the one you are using in ASP. I am not trying to be mean, but it seems that you are being stubborn towards your code without noticing it. =)

Comment: @Ricardo.. Thanks. But, i need the help here is i can not go and replace those special characters specially (replace command). Because, i am loading the data in batch mode, the query is being derived dynamically. I found that these two special characters are there in my data as of now. I can handle them manually. In future, i want to handle all exceptions. Thanks again.

Comment: One more comment to add as, Oracle can accept those values.. Only my Vbscript is not handling this character. I have changed the character set to unicode-8, it didnt work.

Comment: if the character come from your data, and inserted in dynamic SQL used in the execute; then, clean the string before you pass it to the Execute function. And by your explanation itself, that is why SqlPlus works fine, because there you type the query manually, thus, it does not contains the EOF character.

Comment: @Ricardo. actually, the issue is not EOF character. Whenever, my script found the special character, it will throw the above error. If i copy the problematic query and paste into my SQL tool, it works fine (i found that when i am pasting the script in my sql tool, the character set got changed it seems ). In ASP environment, it is failing. My database NLS character set value is UTF8. But, i set my character set in my ASP script, it didnt work. Please help, thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo, Just now, i validated the client environment (where my script is running), oracle nls language has been set as **WE8MSWIN1252**. I am not sure with NLS langauge setup. please confirm whether it will allow special character (example chr(237), chr(233)).

Comment: I dont think we are understanding each other. I am trying to tell you that 'copy and paste' will not contain the character. The encoding in your database has nothing to do with the problem. If you include the EOF in the middle of the SQL statement to be executed, the parser will complain, because the statement will be truncated to that point. The source appears to be your data. use some string replacement over the string variable containing your SQL before trying execution.

Comment: btw, I came to discover, as far as EOF is concerned, that there is no such thing as an EOF character. That particular bit is a misnomer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have special/control characters in the SQL statement to be executed. Statements are parsed and validated before execution, and an exception will be raised if the statement is invalid.

Here is one of many possible approaches.

```
[...]
sqlStatement="SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE dar = 'stuff' "

sqlStatement = strClean(sqlStatement ) 

Set recordset = connection.Execute (sqlStatement, RecordsAffected, Options) 
[...]



Function strClean (strtoclean)
Dim objRegExp, outputStr
Set objRegExp = New Regexp

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "((?![a-zA-Z0-9]).)+"
outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(strtoclean, "-")

objRegExp.Pattern = "\-+"
outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(outputStr, "-")

strClean = outputStr
End Function
```

Replace function from:
http://www.code-tips.com/2009/04/vbscript-string-clean-function-remove.html

In your particular case, base on the error observed.

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 616: PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 359: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 717: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;

Debug your statement by printing the contents of the SQL statement you passed to 'execute'.

Also, examine "line 1, column 359" you are missing a comma there (or some other mistake in the SQL statement is confusing the parser).